# Laravel, Reusable API Resource method

Tags: laravel, api, resources, extend

So I've created an API Resource and in the `toArray()` method, I've filtered which attributes get returned via query strings. I want to be able to do this for most of my API Resources so it makes sense to move this into a reusable method. What would be the best way of doing this?

I was thinking about extending the base `Resource` but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Or should it be moved into a service class or repository?

My method is below;

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    if($request->fields) {
        $fields         = [];
        $selectedFields = explode(',', $request->fields);
        foreach($selectedFields as $field) {
            if(isset($this->{$field})) {
                $fields[$field] = $this->{$field};
            }
        }
        return $fields;
    } else {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like...

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    if($request->fields) {
        return parent::filterFields($request); // Not sure whether it should be parent::, $this or something else?
    } else {
        return parent::toArray($request); // Not sure whether it should be parent::, $this or something else?
    }

    // or event just
    return parent::filterFields($request); // Not sure whether it should be parent::, $this or something else?
}
```

Full Classes:

**ProjectResource.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ProjectResource extends Resource
{

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        dd(parent::filterFields());
        // or
        dd($this->filterFields());

        if($request->fields) {
            $fields         = [];
            $selectedFields = explode(',', $request->fields);
            foreach($selectedFields as $field) {
                if(isset($this->{$field})) {
                    $fields[$field] = $this->{$field};
                }
            }
            return $fields;
        } else {
            return parent::toArray($request);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class Test extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filterFields($request)
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're extending the class, you can use either `parent::` or `$this->`.  The difference being  `parent` will always refer to the parent class, `$this` will only refer to the parent if the method does not exist on the current class. Therefore, using `$this` allows extension of methods and properties.

Example:

```
<?php
class A {
    public function test() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function test() {
        echo 'B';
    }

    public function callParent(){
        parent::test();
    }

    public function callThis() {
        $this->test();
    }
}


$b = new B();
$b->callParent(); // Echoes A
$b->callThis(); // Echos B
```

---

In your updated class representation, you have both classes extending Resource but ProjectResource will have no idea about the methods in Test.  You would need ProjectResource to extend Test, which will also inherit methods from Resource since Test extends Resource (multiple inheritence).

---

Beyond that, how you implement is going to be opinion based and you have lots of options.  You can extend an abstract class, you can use a dedicated filtering class, or you can use a trait.

Comment: I tried both but neither worked, `get_parent_class` returns the Resource class, but when I try `parent::filterFields()` or `$this->filterFields()` I get `Call to undefined method App\Project::filterFields()`, so it looks like it's referring to a different class?

Comment: Can you post your full classes?

Comment: Also, to clarify, I want to extend the Resource class so that filterFields is available to all instances of it.

Comment: ProjectResource would have to extend Test, not Resource.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, don't know why I didn't realise that earlier! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the resource

```
  <?php
        
        namespace App\Http\Resources;
        
        use App\Http\Resources\Product as ProductResource;
        
        class ProductQuantity extends ProductResource
        {
            /**
             * Transform the resource into an array.
             *
             * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
             * @return array
             */
            public function toArray($request)
            {
                $parent = parent::toArray($request);
        
                return array_merge($parent, [
                    'depotsQuantity' => $this->warehouses->sum('pivot.quantity'),
                ]);
            }
        }
```